# ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio not working on MacOS

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, cplex, macos-catalina, ibm-ilog-opl

I tried to use ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio on my MacBook. The installation worked fine, but after startup the application is literally unusable.
I created a empty Project, when I click any file I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. In the preferences, when I try to access any page I just get a error that the current page has wrong values.
Any Idea how to fix that. My colleague has exactly the same problems. I have currently installed 12.10, but already tried with 12.9 which shows the same errors.

Edit: Tried it on macOS Catalina and Big Sur with the same behaviour

Comment: You may want to mention which version of macOS you are using, exactly.

Comment: Sorry completely forgot that. I added it, Thank you :)

Comment: About macOS Catalina, are you still on 10.15.6? Or did you already update to 10.15.7?  We've never heard of such issues with 10.15.6, but it seems that 10.15.7 and Big Sur cause trouble with the IDE.
Apple menu -> 'About This Mac' will give you the exact version.

Comment: My colleague is currently not at home and I have only BigSur on my machine. I'll create a Mojave / Catalina 10.15.6 VM later to test.
Anyway, if this is the problem, will there be a fix soon?

Comment: @XavierNodet in fact it works on macOS Mojave. Hopefully there will be a fix for that soon!